# AVAudioPlayer not playing long sounds?

Tags: ios, audio, avaudioplayer

I have a series of sound files ranging from 0.3s to 3.0s.

When trying to play with AVAudioPlayer, I get nothing, *unless* I add a `sleep(4)` call after to ensure the sound can play. Really weird.

Apart from that, no errors with the error param that gets passed in, and the `[player play]` returns `YES` every time. The delegate methods are not called, though, oddly enough.

Here's my code.

(.m file)

```
@interface MyClass ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *soundPlayer;
@end

@implementation SLInspireKit
//view did load here

- (void)playRandomSound {
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];

    NSError *error;

    NSString *musicFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"my-sound-%d.aiff", arc4random_uniform(8)];
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], musicFileName];
    NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

    self.soundPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundUrl error:&error];
    self.soundPlayer.delegate = self;
    [self.soundPlayer setVolume:1.0];
    [self.soundPlayer prepareToPlay];

    if ([self.soundPlayer play]){
        NSLog(@"Played fine");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Did not play fine");
    }
    sleep(1); //uncomment this out, and nothing. Set to 1, first second of each sound, 2, 2 seconds and so on. 

}
```

Any ideas? I don't think it's an ARC thing, but it could be :/ I have to initiate each time because the sound changes each time.

Comment: Can you show the code that calls this method? I think your problem is that you want to implement a 'shuffle' playlist and you are just calling the method without waiting for the sound to finish playing, right? The play method is not blocking  ;)

Comment: If this is not the case you should probably implement the setSoundPlayer: method and check when it's called you don't overwrite your soundplayer and thereby deallocating it.

Comment: It's attached to a button. If I tap the button, nothing happens (yet the code IS being called, confirmed with breakpoints etc). 

If I add the sleep(n) back in, it starts playing immediately

Comment: Is it possible that the entire class that holds the reference to the soundPlayer is deallocated? Can you just for gigles remove the @property and just use static AVAudioPlayer *soundPlayer; instead? (You will also have to remove all the "self."

Comment: Ha! Good spotting. Yes I was. In a rush to test this class, I initiated it on the button click, which would have been released. DERP. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick summary of the comments:
Turns out the sleep(n) was needed since the entire class containing the AVAudioPlayer was deallocated.

Retaining the class fixes the issue.

Cheers!